# Можно ли восстанавливать свой удаленный вопрос, меняя тему и вопрос кардинально

Tags: поддержка

Меня давеча заблокировали, не могу задавать вопросы. И я решил схитрить, у меня все 3 удаленных вопроса. выбрал тот который мало просматривали и ни как не комментировали. Восстановил его, и кординально изменил, я получил ответ на свой новый вопрос.  И после я вернул себе возможность писать вопросы. Это было утром, но вот сейчас вечером, почему-то не могу задавать вопросы... Правильно ли я поступил? Можно ли так делать?

Comment: Вопрос менять на другой нельзя. Для этого создавайте новый. То, что Вам это запрещают, говорит о том, что Вы не научились нормально пользоваться сайтом. Почитайте справку, исправьте удалённые вопросы (они даже удалённые считаются в формуле readonly бана).

Comment: 2 вопроса  с отрицательным статусом, это уже повод блокировкм?

Comment: Я не знаю формулы вычисления. Быть может и повод.

Comment: @Air если честно - я не совсем понимаю, почему вы попали под блокировку. удаленные посты не учитываются автобаном ([Deleted posts are mostly irrelevant to the question ban. If someone tells you otherwise, tell them they're wrong; if you see a meta post that says otherwise, edit it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/1988244)), все остальные посты выгядят нормально, все с положительным рейтингом

Comment: ок, судя по всему, учитывается баланс голосов на недавних вопросов (неизвестно как) - вас забанили за минус на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714873. Т.е. сейчас ваш аккаунт в таком положении, что если я снимаю свой плюс с одного из вопросов - вас банят. Если возвращаю плюс - бан снимается :) Срабатывает даже при минусовании/плюсовании вопросов за июль.

Comment: я даже не знаю как переформулировать свои вопросы,  удаленые, и стоит ли их восстанавливать

Comment: PashaPash, благодарю,  блокировку сняли, уверен, твоя заслуга